# Page numbering for a blog

Tags: blogs

I am building a blog for someone atm I'm not using anything like Wordpress etc..

My question is: how can I make a page numbering system as you see in many blogs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're making everything by hand and want pagination, you can try this (assuming you're using SQL):

1. decide the number of items you want per page
2. query the db to get total number of items
3. calculate total number of pages to know how many page links to print
4. query for items by using LIMIT and OFFSET

Comment: I'll definitely try that, thanks for the answer!